# Prove a cycle of length l is odd if l is even?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

This is my first course on Group Theory. How do I go about proving this?

Comment: For starters, do you understand the definitions of "length" of a cycle and "parity" of a permutation? (Separately, it would be polite to _include the statement of the question_ in the body of the post. Titles have a way of getting separated psychologically from the rest of the post.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Is length just the number of elements in the permutation?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$(a_1\ a_2\ \dots\ a_l) = (a_1\ a_l)(a_1 a_{l-1})\cdots(a_1\ a_2)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Prove it by iteration on the length $l$ of the cycle.

Clear if $l=2$ as in that case the cycle is a transposition which is odd.

Then prove that if a cycle of length $l$ can be written as a product of $l-1$ transpositions, a cycle of length $l+1$ is the product of $l$ transpositions.

To simplify the problem, it is possible by conjugaisons to suppose that the cycle is $(12 \dots l)$.